# Which portions of code execute in Tensorflow vs. Python interpreter?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In Tensorflow, we typically have one block of code to set up the computation graph and a second block to run the session, e.g.:

```
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    ...Computation graph code here...
    ...
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
    ... code to run the graph here...
    ...
```

In both of these blocks, what rules determine whether the code is executed in the dark and mysterious world of Tensorflow (and in particular the GPU) vs. the Python interpreter? My assumption is that only those functions that begin with `tf.` are executed within the Tensorflow universe, and everything else is handled by Python? So, if I add some Python code, in either the "graph" block or the "session" block, then it will not gain the speed advantages available via Tensorflow's compiled code and GPU libraries, and this could slow things down a lot, correct?

---

### Update 2016.6.5:

Example: Let's say I want to create a loss function different than those provided by Tensorflow. I have already done this in a minor way with the following lines, inside the `with graph.as_default():` block. This code calculates loss with L2 regularization:

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean (tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, tf_train_labels))
L2loss = L2weight * (tf.nn.l2_loss(weightsLayer2) + tf.nn.l2_loss(weightsLayer1))
loss = loss + L2loss
```

The first line is pure Tensorflow. The latter 2 lines are Tensorflow + python. The python portion can be arbitrarily complex. I can understand that all of the `tf` functions are executed inside Tensorflow, but in the 2nd and 3rd lines above, are the additions and multiplication also executed by Tensorflow, or are they executed by "jumping out" of Tensorflow to the Python interpreter, and then returning to Tensorflow? If so, does this entail a performance penalty? Should I be doing that addition and multiplication in the `session` block and then returning the result back to Tensorflow via a feed dictionary (which would also involve a performance penalty)? The final loss is needed within the `graph` block by the optimizer.

Comment: `session.run` is where TensorFlow kicks in, everything else is Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand TensorFlow, the first part where you define the graph should be written only with TensorFlow functions. If you want to add some python it should be separated from the graph and added via placeholders (`tf.placeholder`).

On the other side, in the `tf.Session()` part, you will call the graph results through `sess.run()`, providing the `feed_dict` values (python objects, mostly arrays). Then, the results you obtain will be python objects so here the Python interpreter will do the job.

---

To sum it up:

1. In the first part, you define the TensorFlow graph (compiled by TensorFlow). This is where all the heavy calculus should be.
2. In the second part, the code you run is in Python but calls the TensorFlow graph through `sess.run()`, which is run by TensorFlow (and should contain most of the calculus)

---

### UPDATE

To answer your updated question, you should whenever possible make all computations using TensorFlow functions (because it will be much faster). Now if you need to do some computations impossible to do in TensorFlow, the only way to do this is by calling `sess.run()` and using placeholders to feed the value back in the graph.

This is a case of last resort, as it will be very slow compared to a TensorFlow implementation !

```py
loss = tf.constant(0.5)  # in the TensorFlow graph

# Now you want to do some computations in Python, and obtain the value loss_bis
loss_bis = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [])
res = ...  # the TensorFlow graph continues

with tf.Session() as sess:
  loss_value = sess.run(loss)
  # PYTHON COMPUTATIONS
  loss_bis_value = something_complicated_and_impossible_in_tf(loss_value)
  sess.run([...], feed_dict={loss_bis=loss_bis_value})
```

Comment: Thanks Olivier. This helps. I clarified my question above - please see more details.

Comment: Every operation like + and * applied to a `tf.Tensor` will be seen as `tf.add()` or `tf.mul()`. If you type `type(loss)` you will find that it is indeed a Tensor in the TensorFlow graph.